# what is the difference between update and upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, apt-get

In apt-get command, what is the major effects of update and upgrade?
I didn't see any difference besides the wording.
It seems like update is about system package whereas upgrade is about software package. If that is the case, how to tell which is system package and which is software package?

Comment: Already answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/94102/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-update-and-upgrade

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### From `man apt`

> ```
>   update
>       update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their
>       sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the
>       location(s) specified in /etc/apt/sources.list...
> ```

...

> ```
>   upgrade
>       upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
>       currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
>       /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
> ```

In simple words: `apt-get update` will update *apt's database*, the list of available packages (and version's date and number). Where `apt-get dist-upgrade` will upgrade all packages installed in your system (... if date and/or version differ).

Answer (score 4):

update updates the list of available packages and their versions, but it does not install or upgrade any new packages.

upgrade actually installs newer versions of the packages you have.

Answer (score 0):

The main objectives of update is to provide bug and errors fixes to present existing system....

The main objectives of upgrade is to introducing new features and functionalities to an existing system...

Upgrading involves transforming old system into newer version.....

Answer (score -2):

Difference between update and upgrade is as:

1. Update make changes to an app or operating system in such a way that it not affects its core structure. Like bug fixes, security patches, adding support for drivers and new hardware, etc can be termed as Update.
   While when set of changes made to a software are significant and substantial enough then is called as Upgrade.
2. Updates are smaller than upgrades. Like update of OS can be of few hundred megabytes, but upgrade of OS can be of several Gigabyte.
3. Updates take smaller time than Upgrades. It could take several hours to upgrade complete system.
4. Updates are always free while upgrade can cost you.
5. An upgrade can result in change in software version while update will not change version of software.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I think you have not read my answer properly. I suggest you to read my answer once again, May be you get things that are absolutely true.

Comment: I did read the answer. It gave me the distinct impression that you did not understand the question. In particular the bit where it said **In apt-get command**